# Edit comment , nested form through Zurb Reveal - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation-6, zurb-reveal

First of all this is the error

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

What I have is a Thread model and controller and a Answer model and Controller.
And what I am trying to do is edit the answer on the show page of the thread via a zurb Reveal Modal.

and this what my code looks like

**Thread Modal**

```
class Thread < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :user
  has_many    :answers

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :subject, use: :slugged
end
```

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :thread
end
```

**Answer Controller**

```
def edit
    @thread = Thread.friendly.find(params[:thread_id])
    @answer = @thread.answers.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => false
end

def update
    @thread = Thread.friendly.find(params[:thread_id])
    @answer = @thread.answers.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @answer.update(params[:answer].permit(:content))
            format.html { redirect_to thread_path(@thread) }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @answer }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to @thread, alert: "Unable to save your post" }
            format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**Show Thread**

```
<%= render @thread.answers %>
```

**Answer Partial**

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.id == answer.user_id %>
<ul class="edit-links pull-right">
    <li>

        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_thread_answer_path(answer.thread, answer), :remote => true, class: "edit", "data-open" => "editModal", "data-open-ajax" => edit_thread_answer_path(answer.thread, answer) %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', [answer.thread, answer], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "destroy" %>
    </li>
</ul>

<% end %>
<p>
    <%= simple_format answer.content %>
</p>

<div id="editModal" class="reveal" data-reveal>
    <%= render :partial => 'answers/edit_form' %>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**Answer Edit Form Partial**

```
<h1>Edit Answer</h1>

<%= form_for([@thread, @answer]) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => "10" %>

    <%= f.submit "Update", :class => "button add-thread" %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error when I try to open a thread#show

its says the error is here

```
ArgumentError in Threads#show
<%= form_for([@thread, @answer]) do |f| %>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/answers/_answer.html.erb, app/views/threads/show.html.erb

Any suggestions ? where may the error be ?